# Is there a "tracing" service that comes with Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

This page: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/#option-2-insecure-access-http

Shows how to setup external visibility to the telemetry addons for Istio.  One of those is shown to be "tracing".  It instructs to create a virtual service like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: tracing-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "tracing.${INGRESS_DOMAIN}"
  gateways:
  - tracing-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: tracing
        port:
          number: 80
```

This seems to imply that there is a service that can be installed that holds traces.  But all I can find is docs on how to integrate with Jaegar, Lightstep and Zipkin.  Nothing for a standalone tracing service.

Is there a such a thing?  And if so is there any docs on how to install it?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/telemetry/#Tracing
https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/

> Istio leverages Envoy’s distributed tracing feature to provide tracing integration out of the box. Specifically, Istio provides options to install various tracing backend and configure proxies to send trace spans to them automatically. See Zipkin, Jaeger and Lightstep task docs about how Istio works with those tracing systems.